# Does this guitar tuning have a name?

Tags: guitar, tuning, alternative-tunings

I've had a few suggestions as to an "official" name for this tuning, but what do you lot think?

From high e to bass...

`e B F# C# G# D#`

Comment: I've added the `alternative-tunings` tag to differentiate questions between the acting of `tuning` and actual `alternative-tunings`.

Comment: It's really weird to list the strings high-to-low. This isn't Ancient Ionia!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you start with the low string, despite the fact that we begin counting strings with the high string, and this would be D# G# C# F# B E then, which would be very similar to Stanley Jordan's tuning, EADGCF, which is exactly like standard except the strings above the major third are sharpened. "All Fourths" would be a way to express it, but I don't think I've seen it said like that.

The good of it is that, for playing melodically, all the patterns are the same when you change strings, which isn't true of standard. The bad of it, of course, is that chords get all messed up.

Comment: I've heard "all fourths" for this type of tuning.

Answer (score 7):

A search of a chord dictionary throws up the the tuning to be an Emaj13 chord, so I suppose technically the name would be 'Open Emaj13.' Not particularly catchy though, and I don't think there is a real name for it, as far as I know. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

You can name this 'half of [circle of fifths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_fifths) (starting on E)' as '[stacked-fourths](http://www.google.com/search?q=stacked%20fourths) on D#' tuning.